# Why does VQE with pennylane and scikit-optimize gp_minimize give 'func must be scalar' error?

Tags: simulation, vqe, pennylane

I am trying to replace the SPSA optimizer in the VQE tutorial of [pennylane](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/spsa.html) by the bayesian optimizer of [scikit-opimize](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.gp_minimize.html).

When running the code below I get the error "func should return a scalar".

I think this is not actually the problem since my func, `wrapped_cost`, returns a scalar which I also print. But I have no idea what the real problem is.

````
import pennylane as qml
from pennylane import qchem
from pennylane import numpy as np
from skopt import gp_minimize

niter_spsa = 200
true_energy = -1.136189454088
seednum=10
num_params=3
devicename="default.qubit"

#setup hamiltonian
symbols = ["H", "H"]
coordinates = np.array([0.0, 0.0, -0.6614, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6614])
h2_ham, num_qubits = qchem.molecular_hamiltonian(symbols, coordinates)

# Variational ansatz for H_2 
def circuit(params, wires):  #has 3 parameters
    qml.BasisState(np.array([1, 1, 0, 0]), wires=wires)
    for i in wires:
        qml.Rot(*params[i], wires=i)
    qml.CNOT(wires=[2, 3])
    qml.CNOT(wires=[2, 0])
    qml.CNOT(wires=[3, 1])


dev=qml.device(devicename, wires=num_qubits)

def exp_val_circuit(params):
    circuit(params, range(dev.num_wires))
    return qml.expval(h2_ham)

##
cost_spsa = qml.QNode(exp_val_circuit, dev)

def wrapped_cost(params):  # Wrapping the cost function and flattening the parameters to be compatible with noisyopt which assumes a flat array of input parameters
    return cost_spsa(np.asarray(params).reshape(num_qubits, num_params))


##callback for documentation =^intermediate_results in (3)
def callback_fn(xk):
    cost_val = wrapped_cost(xk)

##set initial parameters
np.random.seed(seednum)
init_params = np.random.normal(0, np.pi, (num_qubits, 3), requires_grad=True)
params = list(init_params.copy().reshape(num_qubits * num_params)) #flatten and convert to list (func of gp_minimize takes list as input)

testlist=[i for i in range(12)]
print("Test for wrapped_cost: ",wrapped_cost(testlist), " with tensor list params: ",wrapped_cost(params))

##do optimization
res = gp_minimize(
        wrapped_cost,
        [(2.0,4.0),(-5.0,0.0),(-6.0,-4.0),(0.0,6.0),
        (0.0,2.0),(-3.0,-2.0),(0.0,2.0),(-3.0,0.0),
        (-2.0,2.0),(-4.0,0.0),(0.0,2.0),(1.0,4.0)], #search space chosen on basis of observed parameters in minimizeSPSA for seed 10 
        n_calls=20, #number of calls to the function to be evaluated
        n_initial_points=20, #number of evaluations of the function before approximating it with base_estimator
        random_state=0, #seed
        verbose=True,
        callback=callback_fn
    )
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.asscalar` as stated by Catalina solves the described problem.

Further problems (e.g. error message `cannot convert (1,) array into (3,4) at np.asscalar(cost_spsa(np.asarray(params).reshape(num_qubits, num_params)))`) arise, because `xk` used in the callbackfunction is not just the set of current parameters as for the Spsa but `gp_minimize` is much more verbose. Thus, also the additional evaluation of the costfunction in the callback is not needed but it is enough to just output `xk` to get all the needed information.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your error. I made several tests on your code and I found that the wrapped_cost function is returning a tensor, not a scalar. However if you try to use something like np.asscalar this causes problems down the line. I don't have a solution to your problem but hopefully this uncovers the root of the problem and you may be able to solve it from here.

Comment: Thank you. This helped to solve the issue.